# Why is blitting images on the screen making my game very very slow?

Tags: python, pygame

im blitting a health bar onto the screen and seems like blitting the images on screen is causing the problem, i removed the for loop and whenever im making the player jump it seems like the performance is very very bad and when i remove the entire function the player was moving fast and jumping fast rather than being very very slow. What could be causing this issue? /(pls forget about the screens[0].blit that has nothing to do with the problem)

code:

```
def lives(lives_image1, lives_image2, x,y,lives_amount,lives_amount2, draw_lives):
    if len(screens) >= 1:
        if draw_lives:
            for i in range(lives_amount2):
                screens[0].blit(pygame.image.load(lives_image2),(x + pygame.image.load(lives_image2).get_width() * i,y))
            for i in range(lives_amount):
                screens[0].blit(pygame.image.load(lives_image1), (x + pygame.image.load(lives_image1).get_width() * i,y))
    if lives_amount <= 0:
        lives_amount = 0
    return lives_amount
    pass
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your application is slow because you are loading the images from the file every frame. Load the images once before the application loop, but `blit` them every frame:

```py
def load_lives(lives_image)
    return pygame.image.load(lives_image);

def lives(lives1_surf, lives2_surf, x, y, lives_amount, lives_amount2, draw_lives):
    if len(screens) >= 1:
        if draw_lives:
            for i in range(lives_amount2):
                screens[0].blit(lives2_surf,(x + lives2_surf.get_width() * i, y))
            for i in range(lives_amount):
                screens[0].blit(lives1_surf, (x + lives1_surf.get_width() * i, y))
    if lives_amount <= 0:
        lives_amount = 0
    return lives_amount
```

```py
lives1_surf = load_lives(lives_image1);
lives2_surf = load_lives(lives_image2);

while run:
    # [...]

    lives(lives1_surf, lives2_surf, ......)

    # [...]
```

Note that [`pygame.image.load`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/image.html#pygame.image.load) is a very expensive operation. This function needs to load the image file from disk and finally needs to the decode the image.

Comment: omg rabbid you again omg, thank you soo much, i love you soo much, because i always see you everywhere helping people left and right. Gratefull for your help

Comment: but im calling out the function from another file and that file is in a while loop, so i have to run the function in a while loop, so how can i load the image from outside of the loop using the file that contains the function??

Comment: ?? can you give me an example pls.

Comment: yeah that works but the thing is i need to load the images from outside the file that contains the while loop (the file that contains the function). Thats essential.

Comment: @Morris I changed the answer again

Comment: yeah i saw that, thanks rabbid. <3